# Android OS で標準対応のコーデック利用時にライセンス費用は発生する？

Tags: android, ライセンス, decode

Android OSが基本的にサポートしているコーデックをアプリ内で使用する場合は、別途ライセンス料を支払う必要はありませんか？

Comment: コーデックの著作権によるんじゃないですか？　著作者が詐称されてた場合わかりづらいですが…。ソースコードからコンパイルした場合はどうだったかな…。

Answer (score 0):

支払う必要は無いはずです。以下は H.264 の例ですが、H.265 も事情は大きく変わらないと思います。

> By leaving the decoding up to the hardware, Mozilla also leaves the license costs up to the hardware suppliers.
> （Mozilla は、デコードをハードウェアに任せることで、ライセンス費用もハードウェア サプライヤーに任せることになります。）
> —— [Mozilla ships Firefox with H.264 support on Android](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/mozilla-ships-firefox-with-h-264-support-on-android/)

---

> If your software can encode or decode H.264 video, but it calls some API from the OS or the browser to do the job, you don’t need to pay the license fee since the hardware/OS/browser vendors already have you covered.
> （あなたのソフトウェアが H.264 ビデオをエンコードまたはデコードできるが、その作業を行うために OS またはブラウザから何らかの API を呼び出す場合は、ハードウェア/OS/ブラウザのベンダーがすでにカバーしているため、あなたはライセンス料を支払う必要はありません。）
> —— [Settle your questions about H.264 license cost once and for all (hopefully)](https://jina-liu.medium.com/settle-your-questions-about-h-264-license-cost-once-and-for-all-hopefully-a058c2149256)